# Is there a CityHash Python (2.7) Implementation for Google App Engine?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, hash, google-bigquery

I'm planning an application and BigQuery seems to fit the bill, BUT there's an issue.

The hash in BigQuery is CityHash (1.0.3) and I'd like to use Google App Engine (Python 2.7) to write the application.

All I need know how to do is take strings and create hashes that match the BigQuery hash function in the standard python 2.7 ecosystem on app engine (or how to extend it to do that).

I know that could send a query to BigQuery to calculate the hashes that I need but BigQuery isn't meant to be used that way (and it will result in unacceptable latency).

Comment: Hey Gary! Welcome to Stack :). I'm the one who edited your question to remove the unnecessary "fluff" and meta question at the end. While I did not downvote you, I can tell you that your question is a bit too broad for Stack, which is possibly why you're getting downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The code for cityhash 1.0.3 is still available here: https://code.google.com/p/cityhash/downloads/detail?name=cityhash-1.0.3.tar.gz
But it is C code which won't be allowed inside App Engine. If you have mastery of python, you could rewrite it in Python. There is a test suite to verify the correctness. Sorry, this is the best I could come up with.

Comment: Thanks Mosha, I'm new to Python so rewriting is probably beyond me - although I will look at it as I'm sure others would appreciate the function.